# How to solve the following with substitution…

Tags: sequences-and-series

$T_{n} = 2T_{n-1} + 4$

I've tried substituting in $T_{n-1}$, $T_{n-2}$, etc, but I still don't know the pattern or general form. I am looking to solve this equation with the substitution technique.

Comment: Try $U(n)=T(n)-4$.

Comment: @Akababa That's the right idea, but it should be $\,U(n)=T(n)\color{red}{+}4\,$ for $\,U(n)\,$ to be a GP.

Answer (score 1):

(*Based on @Akababa's comment under the OP, and posted as CW*.)

The recurrence has the constant solution $\,T_n=-4\,$, which suggests looking at the differences $\,T_n-(-4)\,$. That in turn leads to $\require{cancel}\,T_{n} \color{red}{+4} = 2T_{n-1} \color{red}{+8-\bcancel{4}}+ \bcancel{4}\,$ $\iff T_n+4 = 2(T_{n-1}+4)$. It follows that $\,T_n+4\,$ is a GP with common ratio $2$, so in the end $T_n+4 = 2^n(T_0+4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:  divide by $2^n$ and write it as $\,\dfrac{T_n}{2^n}=\dfrac{T_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}+ \dfrac{1}{2^{n-2}}\,$, telescope and sum the GP on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

$$T_n = 2T_{n-1} + 4$$

Start by looking at $T(1)$
$$T(1) = 2T(0) + 4 $$
Substitute in $T(1)$ into your expression for $T(2)$
$$T(2) = 2(2(T(0) + 4) + 4 $$
Simplify
$$T(2) = 4T(0) + 8 + 4 $$
Thus we can extend this to the case of $T(n)$

$$T(n) = 2^{n}T(0) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i} $$

Which gives you a big oh runtime of 
$$T(n) = 2^n $$

Comment: Just a nitpick, but the exception case $T(0)=-4$ needs to be excluded, since in that case $T(n)=-4$.